# Polymer iron-ajax response code

Tags: javascript, polymer

I am using Polymer 1.6 and `<iron-ajax>` for my API calls. I cannot distinguish between these two situations based on `iron-ajax-error` event:

1. Basic authentication failure on back-end (browser returns `403 Forbidden`)
2. Service not found (browser returns `404 Not Found`)

In both situations, the response body is empty **even though** in the authentication problem, the server responds with a JSON body.

I would like to read the response status code, or be able to get the response body in situation 1.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When the server responds with an error, the response body is supposed to be `null` according to the [spec](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#response-body). However, `<iron-ajax>`'s event detail still provides access to the status code and status text.

#### `<iron-ajax>.response` event

The event detail of the [`<iron-ajax>.response`](https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/iron-ajax#event-response) event is an [`<iron-request>`](https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/iron-request). The status code is stored in [`<iron-request>.status`](https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/iron-request#property-status) and the corresponding text is in [`<iron-request>.statusText`](https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/iron-request#property-statusText):

```js
_onResponse: function(e) {
  const req = e.detail; // iron-request
  console.log('status', req.status, req.statusText);
}
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    _onResponse: function(e) {
      const req = e.detail;
      console.log('response', req.status, req.statusText);
      this.responseStatus = req.status;
      this.responseStatusText = req.statusText;
    },
    _onError: function(e) {
      const req = e.detail.request;
      const err = e.detail.error;
      console.log('error', err, req.status, req.statusText);
      this.errorStatus = req.status;
      this.errorStatusText = req.statusText;
      this.errorMessage = err;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.11.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <iron-ajax url="//httpbin.org/status/200"
                 auto
                 on-response="_onResponse"
                 on-error="_onError"></iron-ajax>
      <div>'on-response' status: [[responseStatus]] ([[responseStatusText]])</div>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

#### `<iron-ajax>.error` event

Note the [`<iron-ajax>.error`](https://beta.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-ajax/iron-ajax#event-error) event's detail is different from that of the `<iron-ajax>.response`. The `error`'s event detail is an object with the following shape:

```
{
  error: String,
  request: iron-request
}
```

So the `<iron-ajax>.error` event handler could read the status and status text as follows:

```js
_onError: function(e) {
  const req = e.detail.request; // iron-request
  console.log('status', req.status, req.statusText);
}
```

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    _onResponse: function(e) {
      const req = e.detail;
      console.log('response', req.status, req.statusText);
      this.responseStatus = req.status;
      this.responseStatusText = req.statusText;
    },
    _onError: function(e) {
      const req = e.detail.request;
      const err = e.detail.error;
      console.log('error', err, req.status, req.statusText);
      this.errorStatus = req.status;
      this.errorStatusText = req.statusText;
      this.errorMessage = err;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.11.1/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <iron-ajax url="//httpbin.org/status/404"
                 auto
                 on-response="_onResponse"
                 on-error="_onError"></iron-ajax>
      <div>'on-error' status: [[errorStatus]] ([[errorStatusText]]) - [[errorMessage]]</div>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/aBYMza?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1):

When I want to see the response for error cases, I register an handler function to `error` event and look up `e.detail.response` or `e.detail.request.xhr.response`, like followings:

```
<dom-module id="my-login">
  <template>
    <iron-ajax url="http://some-url.com" 
           method="POST" 
           content-type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
           body="{{reqBody}}" 
           handle-as="json"
           on-response="onResponse" 
           on-error="onError" id="xhr"></iron-ajax>
  </template>

  <script>
  Polymer({
      is: 'my-component',
      properties: {
        reqBody: {
          type: Object,
          value: {}
        }
      },
      onResponse: function(e) {
        console.log(e.detail.response);
      },
      onError: function(e) {
        // I think one of those two would be what you're looking for.
        console.log(e.detail.response);
        console.log(e.detail.request.xhr.response);
      }
  });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```